# Removing line breaks after fixed length

Tags: notepad++

I have a text file with thousands of XML strings on each line. However, if any XML string exceeds 32767 characters, then the remaining text is moved to next line.
I need to remove such line breaks to ensure each line has a complete XML string.

Sample version of the file content having line break after 55 characters is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding=""?><Policy></Policy>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding=""?><Policy></Policy>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding=""?><Policy>111111111111<
/Policy>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding=""?><Policy></Policy>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding=""?><Policy>2222222222222
</Policy>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding=""?><Policy><A></A>333333
33333</Policy>
```

The output is expected to be as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding=""?><Policy></Policy>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding=""?><Policy></Policy>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding=""?><Policy>111111111111</Policy>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding=""?><Policy></Policy>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding=""?><Policy>2222222222222</Policy>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding=""?><Policy><A></A>33333333333</Policy>
```

Please suggest how this can be done in Notepad++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R(?!<\?xml)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R              # any kind of linebreak
(?!<\?xml)      # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't "<?xml" after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]